# Cannot deploy virtual-server on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I am just exploring and want to helm my k8dash, but got the weird error since I have been able to deploy on AWS EKS.

I am running them on my Minikube `V1.23.2`

My helm version is `v3.6.2`

Kubernetes kubectl version is `v1.22.3`

Basically if I do helm template, the `VirtualServer` would be like this:

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: k8dash
  namespace: k8dash
spec:
  host: namahost.com
  routes:
  - action:
      pass: RELEASE-NAME
    path: /
  upstreams:
  - name: RELEASE-NAME
    port: 80
    service: RELEASE-NAME
```

and I got this error:

```
Error: unable to build Kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "VirtualServer" in version "k8s.nginx.org/v1"
```

It's weird, deploying this one on AWS EKS just fine but locally got this error and I could not find any clue while Googling. Does it has something to do with my tools version?

Comment: You need to install operator of `VirtualServer` along with CRD definition

Comment: @rkosegi sorry i don't get it. so what exactly should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install additional CRDs as both `VirtualServer` and `VirtualServerRoute` are not oob, but nginx resources.

[CustomResourceDefinitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#customresourcedefinitions):

> The CustomResourceDefinition API resource allows you to define custom
> resources. Defining a CRD object creates a new custom resource with a
> name and schema that you specify. The Kubernetes API serves and
> handles the storage of your custom resource. The name of a CRD object
> must be a valid DNS subdomain name.
>
> This frees you from writing your own API server to handle the custom
> resource, but the generic nature of the implementation means you have
> less flexibility than with API server aggregation.

---

[Nginx Create Custom Resources](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/#create-custom-resources)

> Note: **By default, it is required to create custom resource definitions
> for VirtualServer, VirtualServerRoute, TransportServer and Policy.**
> Otherwise, the Ingress Controller pods will not become Ready. If you’d
> like to disable that requirement, configure -enable-custom-resources
> command-line argument to false and skip this section.

Create custom resource definitions for VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoute, TransportServer and Policy resources.

You can find crds under https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/deployments/common/crds:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/
$ cd kubernetes-ingress/deployments
$ git checkout v2.0.3 (or latest, as you wish)

$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_virtualservers.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_virtualserverroutes.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_transportservers.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_policies.yaml
```

After successful applying you will be able to create both `VirtualServer` and `VirtualServerRoute`

Comment: ah yes thanks, been gone for a while with no internet.